# I find myself reversing accumulators at the end of most functions; how can I stop?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I've been working through a book on Functional Programming in Scala (with that very title.)  Running through the exercises, I've found myself frequently reversing my final result when it is gathered with an accumulator.  I recall having similar patterns during my Racket days.  My concern is that I might be making my code slightly messier than necessary and perhaps performing an extra `O(n)` operation (where `n` is the length of the accumulator/result.)

Example:

```
// Produces a List from a Stream, forcing evaluation of all elements.
def toList(): List[A] = {
    def go(l: Stream[A], acc: List[A]): List[A] = {
        l match {
            case Empty if acc.nonEmpty => acc.reverse
            case Empty if acc.isEmpty => Nil
            case Cons(h, t) => go(t(), h() :: acc)
        }
    }
    // "this" is a Stream[A].
    go(this, Nil)
}
```

This pattern of reversing the result to restore the original order is my concern.  Is there a better way (no `reverse` call) to do this in FP in general and in Scala in particular?

Comment: For a `List` it's the lesser of two evils. prepend + reverse is O(n) whereas appending would be O(n^2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using a data structure such as Vector that will append a value at effectively constant time.

So where you have:

```
case Cons(h, t) => go(t(), h() :: acc)
```

use instead:

```
case Cons(h,t) => go(t(), acc :+ h())
```

Then there needn't be a reverse when you return the accumulator.

Comment: Ah, so you are saying that given my datatype, my reverse call is unavoidable, and that for similar singly-linked-list-like datastructures, it will be the right thing to do.  You are also saying that Scala's `Vector` datatype (and probably others) will avoid this overhead if used properly, correct?

Comment: The problem stems from the fact you are prepending to the list as you build it. So the first element you add will end up at the end of the list. In many cases such as yours this will be 'reverse' order. So to solve this you just append the items instead. Where Vector comes in, is that with a Vector (or Stack, or Queue) the append function is performant. Whereas with a List it is not.

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html for further information

Comment: Now you have O(n^2) instead of O(n)

Comment: @talex - No, both append and prepend are O(1) with Vector.  (Kind of.  You could argue for O(log n) also, but the base is large.  So is the constant term.)  Anyway, this operation is definitely not O(n^2).  That's the whole point of this answer!--know your data structures.

Comment: @RexKerr How you can have O(1) for append if you need copy whole vector? Or you use mutable vector. Then you code is misleading and better to separate append and pass `acc` to `Cons` constructor.

Comment: @talex - Vector is not implemented as a (single) array.  It's effectively a hash trie on the index (with a fanout of 32).

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are various approaches, even without turning to non-tailrecursion, which you should not do over the size of a possibly large container.

First you should ask: why do you care? If your code is fast enough, why would you want to avoid the reversal?

Then the simplest solution probably is: use mutable builders locally. There is a ListBuffer for exactly the purpose of building a list by append elements step by step. The implementations in the Scala API use this a lot for performance reasons.

If you do not want to directly use a list buffer you can do a lazy computation and convert it to a list. This might in some cases be more readable than using an accumulator, but it probably wont be more efficient.

```
def map[A,B](list: List[A], f: A => B): Stream[B] = list match {
  case x :: xs  => Stream(f(x)) #:: map(xs, f)
  case Nil => Stream() 
}
map(list, (x: Int) => x + 1).toList
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stay tail-recursive, you should use a [Difference List](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/snapshots/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.3.0-SNAPSHOT/scalaz_2.11-7.3.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar/!/scalaz/DList.html) as your accumulator: they are basically a list with a direct pointer to the `Nil` constructor which allows you to do concatenation in constant time.